# In ASP.NET Core, when should I use PhysicalFileProvider instead of regular FileInfo constructor?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

In ASP.NET Core, I see that I can simply use

```
  FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(..file path..)
```

So, what is special about PhysicalFileProvider? Why do I need to use

```
  IFileProvider physicalProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(blobStoragePath);

  FileInfo fileInfo = physicalProvider.GetFileInfo(..file path..);
```

I believe, there must be some good reasons, and I want to understand that reason.

I understand that, if I use PhysicalFileProvider, I can use dependency injection for IFileProvider. But, hopefully, that is not the main reason for using PhysicalFileProvider.

Thank you.

Comment: In my opinion, the FileInfo which generated from PhysicalFileProvider or FileInfo has no difference. If you want to use  PhysicalFileProvider's other method like watch, you could choose PhysicalFileProvider. If not, you could directly use FileInfo.

Comment: Best way to understand the reasons would be to take a look at the source code https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical/src/PhysicalFileProvider.cs#L237